# How to calculate the number of IPs for a field with the next format with a query in Hive....?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to solve this problem, i have a table in Hive with a customer_id and **ip_range** fields, this last field can have two kinds of formats:

1. **Fixed range of IPs**, with the next notation:

   10.95.112.135-120.95.112.169

   My query should return the number of IPs on that range, 35 included both IPs.
2. **Multiple range of IPs**, with the next notation:

   10.95.112.135-10.95.112.157,10.95.112.157-10.95.112.169

   My query should return the sum of the ranges, 25 IPs in this case.

The result should be the number of IPs for a each customer_id

Example:

```
     customer_ID     ip_range                   

       1             10.95.11.135-120.95.112.169                             
       2             10.95.11.135-120.95.112.159                             
       3             10.95.11.135-120.95.112.140                             
       4             10.95.112.135-10.95.112.157,10.95.112.160-10.95.112.169 
       4             10.95.112.101-10.95.112.102                             
       1             10.95.112.120-10.95.112.124
```

The result should show:

```
     customer_ID     count_IPs                   

       1             40                             
       2             25                             
       3             6                             
       4             35
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Fix your data!  You don't want to be storing ip lists in a string delimited format.  This is bad.  The right way to store an ip list is in a table.  In your case, this would look like:

```
create table CustomerIps (
    CustomerIpId int not null,
    CustomerId int not null,
    IpRangeStart varchar(15),
    IpRangeEnd varchar(15),
    IpRangeStartInt int,
    IpRangeEndInt int
);
```

In addition to the string version of the IP, I would take the effort to convert to the 4-byte form as well (assuming IPv4 address representations).

Then, your query is trivial.